# Materializecss grid of rectangles 3x3

Tags: css, materialize

Stuck with a full-screen grid of rectangles which is 3x3 dimension.

This is a layout:

[image]

here is what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/hbrnszns/ (**ctrl click**)

here is css:

```
.rectangle {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin: 1.66%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #00a388;
}
```

How to properly vertical align inner images in rectangles, and how to do it right overall

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing layout, you can use absolute positioning to put the image in the center. It's a combination of `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`

```css
.light-grass {
  background-color: #79bd8f;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin: 1.66%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #00a388;
    position: relative;
}

.rectangle > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
 <nav class="light-grass z-depth-0" role="navigation">
 </nav>
</div>  

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="rectangle valign-wrapper">
      <span><img class="work-icon" src="http://placehold.it/100x40"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciated! I have noticed that it's not responsive from the bottom for some reason, i'm not even sure if this grid either right